# Copy specific DataSet columns to another DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I want some help in copying certain columns from one dataset into another dataset in C#. The mapping for the columns is stored in the xml file.

Suppose I have a source dataset with columns -

```
calldate, 
percent, 
value
```

and a destination dataset with columns -

```
name,
amount
```

The mapping xml file has, columns from source dataset and destination column names. Exclude attribute helps in identifying if the column will be copied or not.
XML:

```
<data>
  <column name="calldate" destination="name" exclude="false" />
  <column name="percent" destination="" exclude="true" />
  <column name="value" destination="amount" exclude="false" />
</data>
```

How to copy the columns `calldate` and `value` from source dataset to `name` and `amount` columns of the destination dataset respectively? Note: the datatypes will be same - string and double. At this time I am not concerned about the xml part. I will take care of that once I figure out how to copy specific columns to respective column in the destination dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if `dt` is the table you're working with,

```
var newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.Columns.Add("name");
newTable.Columns.Add("amount");
foreach (var row as DataRow in dt.Rows) {
    newTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { row["calldate"], row["value"} });
}
```

Comment: This could probably be made shorter and more elegant with LINQ, but I don't know how LINQ to DataSet works.